# Is there a way to send JSON with DELETE request with Net::HTTP?

Tags: ruby, json, net-http

I am using Net::HTTP for CRUD request in Sinatra application. For a delete request I need to send JSON along with request:

```
uri = URI.parse('http://localhost:3000')    
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
path = '/resource/resource-id'
request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(path)
request.basic_auth('username', 'password')

response = http.request(request)
```

The above code sends DELETE request just fine, but when I send JSON,

```
request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(path, '{"ids": ["abc123"]}')
request.basic_auth('username', 'password')

response = http.request(request)
```

it throws:

```
'400 Invalid URI'
```

I have used HTTParty gem a lot and I know it serves this purpose, but I do not want to include a gem for just one API.

Any help/pointers are greatly appreciated.

**Update**
As @kimball and @Zoker suggested, here is what I did (I am using ruby-2.0.0-p643 MRI):

```
request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(path, {'Depth' => 'Infinity', 
                                       'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
request.body = '{"ids":["abc123"]}'
request.basic_auth('username', 'password')

response = http.request(request)
```

it throws:

```
'400 Invalid URI'
```

**Update 2**
Again as suggested in comments:

```
require 'json'
request.body = {"ids" => ["abc123"]}.to_json
```

result is still the same.

```
response = http.request(request)
=> #<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Invalid URI readbody=true>
```

Comment: I can't replicate your error - the earlier line `request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(path, '{"ids": ["abc123"]}')` is raising a different error. Shouldn't that second argument be a hash for headers? Where are you trying to put your JSON - header/body/form data?

Comment: Thanks @Kimball I have updated my question, adding a hash for headers still throws 400 error

Comment: For completeness you can try `Net::HTTPHeader#set_form_data`, but IIRC it simply converts a hash to query parameters. If possible, too, rather than compose your own JSON it may be less error-prone to `require 'json'` and use `Hash#to_json`. Without knowing what service you are trying to interact with I can't offer much advice; overloading a DELETE request is a fraught task!

Comment: Good point on Hash#to_json, in the code I am doing the same.

Comment: I've tested this as far as I reasonably can on the available info (no knowledge of server) and I can't reproduce your error. My own experience of dealing with external services is dominated by bad documentation - I often end up putting my parameters wherever I can (header, body, query params) until I find something that works. If it's internal, at least you can check your own server code.

Comment: Thanks @Kimball this is external API, and you are right on the poor documentation, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

the Net::HTTP::Delete.new() method provide pass params in header

```
# File lib/net/http.rb, line 1231
def delete(path, initheader = {'Depth' => 'Infinity'})
  request(Delete.new(path, initheader))
end
# via: http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/Net/HTTP.html
```

you can use like this:

```
Net::HTTP::Delete.new(path,{'Depth' => 'Infinity', 'foo' => 'bar'})
```

the params in `Delete.new(path,params)` is a hash, not a string.

more important, the hash value must be a `String`

[UPDATE]

we can put a json string into request.body like this

```
require 'json'

request.body = JSON.generate({'foo'=>'bar','key'=>'value'})
```

or you can generate json string yourself

```
request.body = "{\"foo\":\"bar\",\"key\":\"value\"}"
```

Comment: Though this gave me pointer, can you explain how can I send JSON with the request? as header or body?

Comment: @gouravtiwari21 i have updated my answer , you can pass a json string into request.body , what you need to do is just ensure the json string format is right.

Comment: oops , but it works for me , i get `{"foo":"bar","key":"value"}` from reponse body

Comment: This may be because you are using latest ruby (2.1 or 2.2) ? I am stuck on this project for ruby 2,0

Answer (score 0):

You could also just add and if/elsif statement to your request and apply:

```
elsif delete
    request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(path)
end
```

Where path is your specified URL